# How can probabilities be modeled in a universe where time travel is possible?

Tags: probability, soft-question

Please don't take this as a joke, its actually a serious question. If it sounds silly its only because of my (lack of) understanding of probabilities, but my motivation is genuine.

Lets take the following 2 events:

- $A$: Shooting once at a bullseye and hitting at an specific point $P_A$.
- $B$: Shooting twice at a bullseye and hitting both times in the same point $P_B$.

Under classic asumptions (for some sensible definition of classic) both events have $0$ probability. Right?

Now suppose we have backwards time travel (despite physics contradictions). I can watch where the projectile hits the first time, then go back in time, and make a prediction with probability $1$ for $P_A$. However, even with time travel, event $B$ still has $0$ probability.

My questions are:

- Is there some real difference in how these two events are modeled, or interpreted, or is there (more probably) some logical flaw in my reasoning?
- Does this means that time travel is impossible from a logical point of view, without even looking at physics?

Comment: you might enjoy this; I read the original column in Scientific American, I can't say that I got it myself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomb%27s_paradox

Comment: Exceedingly interesting, thanks for the hint, @WillJagy !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a silly question at all. What you are wondering about is the dependence of the probability of an event on the protocol, and about the precise meaning of such claims as "the probability of even $E$ is $p$". A lot has been written about these issues.

Sometimes, probability is meant to reflect a frequency of occurrence. For instance, a typical interpretation of "the probability of rolling a 6 on an honest die is $1/6$" is that if you roll the die a lot of times, then about $1/6$ of the times you will have rolled a 6, and, moreover, the more times you roll, the closer the ratio will actually get to $1/6$ (kinda). This certainly agrees with our intuition acquired after playing with dice.

Other situation are quite different. For instance, "the probability that intelligent life exists outside of our solar system is 0.76" is not quite frequentists, but instead it is reflecting a certain state of knowledge. After all, either there is life out there or there isn't, so clearly the probability is either $0$ or $1$, we just don't know which.

Situation where the probability of an event seems to change drastically when the protocol changes do not require time-travel. A famous example is the [Monty Hall Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem).

Mathematically, a common way to model probabilities is through measure theory, an approach initiated by Kolmogorov. However, there are other possibilities. For a very good discussion on the essence and foundations of probability I would recommend Jayness' [Probability Theory - The Language of Science](http://books.google.com.fj/books/about/Probability_Theory.html?id=tTN4HuUNXjgC&redir_esc=y) (I believe the first few chapters are freely available online.

Comment: Saying "there eithe is life out there or there isn't, therefore the probabilit is 1 or 0" is a logical fallacy I think. For the concept of probabilities to make sense there at all, you have to assume that there are very many universes, and ask "in what percentage of the ones that have an earth as we know it is there intelligent life on a different planet". That probability isn't zero or one just because *our* universe turns to out to belong to one or the other category. Just like the probability of throwing a 6 isn't 1 just because I just threw a 6.

Comment: I must disagree there @fgp. The frequentist interpretation of probabilities is not the only one. Probabilities can also be seen as expressing levels of certainty. Quite often, as in the case of rolling a die and life in the universe, both interpretations make sense. But (which is my claim), for rolling a die the frequentists approach is very suitable, while for life in the universe the frequentists approach is less appropriate (though I'm not saying it is wrong). Such debates tend to ignite world wars between pure frequentists and pure Baysians. Jaynes is showing a sane middle way.

Comment: The statement is a fallacy also from a purely bayesian point of view I think. Because then (or especially then) you have to be carefull to state the *conditions* under your certainity that $A$ is true is $p$. But you are comparing such levels of certainities under *different* conditions. The first one is the probability that alien life exists given what we know about physics and biology today. The second is the probability that alien life exists under the condition that, well, we know for a certainity that alien life exists or doesn't. Those are two very different probabilities.

Comment: the point I wanted (but failed) to make is that the frequentists approach is quite artificial in the case of life in the universe. Sure, we can imagine having multiple universes, but such a situation is quite far removed from what we actually mean. A simpler example would be: Suppose I hold coin in one of my hands. I know where it is, but you don't (and assume I chose where to place it at random). From your frequentist point of view, the probability of the coin being in my right hand is $1/2$. But from my point of view, since I know where it is, it is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Exactly! But that's not a frequentist vs. bayesian thing. It's a matter of prior knowledge. I think what I mainly disliked about that statement is that it sounds (at least to me) as if there was something paradoxical about the situation, because you write "the probability" both times. That implies that same probability is 0.76 today, and 1 tomorrow after the martians finally showed themselves. But that's not the case - the latter is a very different probability because it includes *more* information.

Comment: I think we agree :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need time travel to come up with these kinds of paradoxa. For example, take a normal 6-sided die. Not the mathematically idealized variety, but a real, physically existing die. Prefererrably one with slightly rounded edges, as most dies have. Now throw the die. *Theoretically*, if you'd know the exactly speed and angular momentum of the die at the moment it leaves your hand, plus the pressure distribution of the air the die travels through, plus a fine-grained 3-D map of the underground it eventually hits, you can simulate the throw, and find the face that will point upwards *before* the die comes to a rest. Say that face is 5. Does that contradict that statement that $P(\text{Die shows 6}) = \frac{1}{6}$? No, it doesn't. It merely says that $$
  P(\text{Die shows 6} | \text{Precise physical cirumstances of the row}) = 0 \text{,} \\
  P(\text{Die shows 5} | \text{Precise physical cirumstances of the row}) = 1 \text{.}
$$

The same goes for time-travel. Time-travelling just saves us from having to do all the tedious computations, because we can just let the *real* world work out the answer, and feed it back in time to us. And, rather unsurprisingly, we find that $$
  P(\text{Die shows 6} | \text{Die showed 6}) = 1
$$
but that doesn't contradict $$
  P(\text{Die shows 6}) = \frac{1}{6} \text{,}
$$
because the two *conditions* are different.

Comment: just to further strengthen the claims: if instead of a die you'd flip a coin, it appears that with practice it is possible to flip the coin in such a way that the probability of it landing on a side of your preference is significantly larger than $1/2$. Thus, the flipper may actually make a fair coin appear biased (and thus also a biased one appear fair).

Comment: @IttayWeiss Nice! That removes the always slightly troublesome "we can compute it" part from the argument. Thanks!

Comment: @IttayWeiss - That's not as difficult as it sounds. I used to be better at doing it, and just attempted it again with worse results than decades ago. First use this seemingly undeniably fair protocol: 1. Place a coin on your thumbnail as one would normally do (to flip a coin). 2. Flip it so it spins an obviously uncountable number of times, over two feet in the air. 3. Snatch the coin out of mid-air as it falls with your 'non-flipping hand' and slap it on the backside of your flipping hand. -- For ease of record keeping flip it heads up each time. -- (continued)

Comment: @IttayWeiss (continuation) -- Does that method seem fair and free of any possibility to cheat ? --- What is the outcome, -- It's far from 50/50 (for me). What result do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the probability of an event happening versus knowledge of that event.

Take scenario $A$. The probability of shooting any particular point is $0$. However the probability of hitting *any* point is $1$ (assuming you don't miss entirely). You just don't know which one. Time travel allows you to know which one, allowing you to make a perfect prediction. The crux of the event is in choosing the proper point.

In scenario $B$, the event itself has probability $0$. The first shot goes anywhere. Time travel lets you know where that will happen. The second shot goes anywhere, but the probability of it going where the first shot is is $0$. The crux of the event is in hitting the same point twice. Knowledge won't change those odds.

So to answer your first question. Scenario $A$ is about an event that will physically happen. You just don't know how it will happen without time travel. Scenario $B$ is about an event that is impossible, and time travel knowledge will not change that. If you were to rephrase the scenarios and add "given that you know exactly were they will go" for the time-travel version, it shows that the scenarios are different. Time-travel $B$ and non-time-travel $B$ having the same answer isn't a flaw, it's how it works in this scenario. Knowledge can't make an impossible event possible.

For the second question, I don't believe this particular example is a logical inconsistency any more than rewinding a tape and predicting what will happen on the second viewing would be.

Comment: Thanks @RandomUser. If I get it right, then there is indeed some intrinsic difference between the meaning of $0$ probability for event $A$ and event $B$. In event $A$, it means that we don't know where will it fall, so our believe is $O$ probability for some fixed point. Knowledge can change that. However, in event $B$, knowledge adds nothing, so can we say that the $0$ probability is more "real" or "meaningful" in event "B"?.

Comment: @AlejandroPiad Pretty much. $A$ is about an event that's impossible to predict without future knowledge, but will certainly happen. $B$ is about an event that is itself impossible, so no level of prediction can help you.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to the dilema is the butterfly effect.

If the probability of hiting point A in your future is near zero, and you wait until after the arrow hits A, and then travel back in time to before the shot was made and shoot again you will find (under this theory of time travel) the probability of hitting A is once again zero. That is, even allowing the possibility of time travel, the universe never unfolds the same way twice.

IMHO, this is the mechanism by which time actually works, any movement away from the present moment, whether forwards or backwards in time, makes it impossibly unlikely to return along the same path to the same circumstance. Thus from the time traveller's perspective all movement in time feels like forward movement.

Comment: This strikes me as philosophical, not mathematical!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the bullseye and bullet have nonzero diameters, the probability of hitting the bullseye is not zero. Second, many people seem to have a penchant for using words to mean something different from their original use and claim the misuse to be an abstraction instead of what it is. This is the case with the word "probability." Now we have "empirical probability" which is an estimate of what or might not be an unknown probability, and "subjective probability" which is imagined, and "classical" or "theoretical probability" which is what probability originally meant and should still mean. This is a common problem in mathematics; e.g., people claim "mulltiplication" is abstract because they apply the same word to operations that are different from repeated addition. It is convenient to do that and not illogical but calling a space a diamond does not make it abstract. It merely makes it confusing.